# Access, ID, Refresh токены

Tags: jwt

Читаю много про токены, но не могу понять кое что

Есть разные виды токенов:

Access позволяет получить доступ к api.

Refresh позволяет обновлять токен.

ID содержит информацию о пользователе, чтобы, например, не бегать все время в базу за его основной инфой, а загрузить из токена.

Но вот что я не могу понять:

Они все состоят из одних и тех же полей, только access токен  должен обязательно включать в себя issuer, audience, subject, чтобы в них указать, какому ресурсу, на  каком ресурсе, какие действия разрешены от имени пользователя?
Я вообще правильно понял назначение полей:

issuer - запрашивающий ресурс

audience - запрашиваемый ресурс(API)

subject - указывает какие действия может делать issuer на audience от имени владельца токена?

А остальные 2 токена не обязаны содержать эти поля?  Есть ли толковое объяснение как формировать все эти 3 токена?

Пока что как будто они формируются одной и той же функцией, просто определенные поля не везде обязательны.